# What's the correct way to capitalize "Spider-Man web slinger toy"?

Tags: capitalization

I am wondering if I should capitalize "web slinger", I don't think I should capitalize toy, but also I don't know if both "Spider-Man's web slinger toy" and "Spider-Man web slinger toy" should be capitalized the same way.

Comment: Why would you capitalize any of those words (aside from *Spider* and *Man*)?

Comment: I see it capitalized on Amazon.

Comment: There's not enough context then. You should tell us whether the quoted is a/the name of a product, or perhaps whether *Spider-Man Web Slinger* is a movie title, with the toy being simply connected to it, etc.

Comment: The choice of words is a bit curious. *Web-slinger* is an established nickname of Spider-Man himself. The gadgets on his wrists are his *web-shooters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sentence, only "Spider-Man" would be capitalised

> I bought a Spider-Man web-slinger toy for my nephew.

As a title of the name of a product, you would use title-case and capitalise all the "major" words.

> **Spider-Man Web-Slinger Toy**
>
> This toy is sold by ...